# How to use divide and conquer and the fact that if one subarray has a majority, the combined array has a majority to find majority element?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

In the question we were told that the crux of the algorithm is the fact that

"When we get down to single elements, that single
element is returned as the majority of its (1-element) array. At every other level, it will get return values from its
two recursive calls. **The key to this algorithm is the fact that if there is a majority element in the combined array,
then that element must be the majority element in either the left half of the array, or in the right half of the array.**"

My implementation was this, probably very buggy but the general idea was this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int merge(int *input, int left, int middle, int right, int maj1, int maj2)
{
    // determine length
    int length1 = middle - left + 1;
    int length2 = right - middle;
    // create helper arrays
    int left_subarray[length1];
    int right_subarray[length2];
    // fill helper arrays
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<length1; ++i)
    {
        left_subarray[i] = input[left + i];
    }
    for (i=0; i<length2; ++i)
    {
        right_subarray[i] = input[middle + 1 + i];
    }
    left_subarray[length1] = 100;
    right_subarray[length2] = 100;
    //both return majority element
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length1; ++i) {
        if (left_subarray[i] == maj1) {
            count1++;
        }
        if (right_subarray[i] == maj1) {
            count1++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length2; ++i) {
        if (right_subarray[i] == maj2) {
            count2++;
        }
        if (left_subarray[i] == maj2) {
            count2++;
        }
    }
    if (count1 > ((length1+length2) - 2)/2){
        return maj1;
    }
    else if (count2 > ((length1+length2) - 2)/2){
        return maj2;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

int merge_sort(int *input, int start, int end, int maj1, int maj2)
{
    //base case: when array split to one
    if (start == end){
        maj1 = start;
        return maj1;
    }
    else
    {
        int middle = (start + end ) / 2;
        maj1 = merge_sort(input, start, middle, maj1, maj2);
        maj2 = merge_sort(input, middle+1, end, maj1, maj2);
        merge(input, start, middle, end, maj1, maj2);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int num;
    scanf("%i", &num);
    int input[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        scanf("%i", &input[i]);
    }
    int maj;
    int maj1 = -1;
    int maj2 = -1;
    maj = merge_sort(&input[0], 0, num - 1, maj1, maj2);
    printf("%d", maj);
    return 0;
}
```

This obviously isn't divide and conquer. I was wondering what is the correct way to implement this, so I can have a better understanding of divide and conquer implementations. My main gripe was in how to merge the two sub-array to elevate it to the next level, but I am probably missing something fundamental on the other parts too.

Disclaimer: This WAS for an assignment, but I am analyzing it now to further my understanding.

Comment: 'This WAS for an assignment' lol, similar Q's asked three times in two days:)

Comment: @MartinJames I only found one similiar question in my search, and it used pairs of number, frequency.

Comment: Try search [c majority](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+majority) for recent related posts.

Comment: for [2,2,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3] I get a left majority 1, and a right maj. of 3, but the overall maj is 2. What did I get wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The trick about this particular algorithm, and why it ends up `O(n log n)` time is that you still need to iterate over the array you are dividing in order to confirm the majority element. What the division provides is the correct *candidates* for this iteration.

For example:

```
[2,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2]
          |maj 3| maj 2
    maj 2 | maj None
 <-------------------> still need to iterate
```

This is implicit in the algorithm statement: "*if* there is a majority element in the combined array, then that element must be the majority element in either the left half of the array." That "if" indicates confirmation is still called for.